# Sorting a hash of hashes

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash that contains a number of keys/values that need sorting by their deepest value.

Here is an example of what I am dealing with:

```
hash = {"en"=> 
    { "key1"=> 
        {"foo1"=>1, 
         "foo2"=>2, 
         "foo3"=>1}, 
      "key2"=>
        {"foo4"=>1,
         "foo5"=>3, 
         "foo6"=>2, 
         "foo7"=>1}
    }
 "fr"=>
    ....
}
```

I want to key each main key (i.e. "en", "fr", es") and sort by the values for the keys within. So having "en" and for "key1" to have "value2" at the top with the highest number (frequency). Then doing the same for the rest of the hash. I'm not bothered about the order of the keys "en", "fr" etc.

So I want the output to be something like this:

```
hash = {"en"=> 
    { "key1"=> 
        {"foo2"=>2, 
         "foo1"=>1, 
         "foo3"=>1}, 
      "key2"=>
        {"foo5"=>3,
         "foo6"=>2, 
         "foo4"=>1, 
         "foo7"=>1}
    }
 "fr"=>
    ....
}
```

Comment: What is the question? And, what have you written?

Comment: ^^^.. I want to sort hash['en'][:key] by it's values for each key

Comment: Please add an example of how the result should look.

Comment: Although it's possible to do this in Ruby 1.9 with its ordered hash, I wonder why you want to rely on hash key order. Surely there might be a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's also important to remember that the hash in 1.9 is not really ordered, it's remembering the insertion order, which is somewhat useful as a FIFO or as a random-access table. For real FIFO and queues or ordered lists it probably makes more sense to use an Array.

Comment: It's simply so I can get words with highest frequencies for certain keys in a 'language' such as en.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragile, but should work:

```
def sort_deep(h)
  if h.values.all?{ |o| o.is_a? Numeric }
    Hash[ h.sort_by{|k,v|[-v,k]} ]
  else
    Hash[ h.map{ |k,v| [ k, sort_deep(v) ] } ]
  end
end
```

Proof:

```
hash = {"en"=> 
    { "key1"=> 
        {"foo1"=>1, 
         "foo2"=>2, 
         "foo3"=>1}, 
      "key2"=>
        {"foo4"=>1,
         "foo5"=>3, 
         "foo6"=>2, 
         "foo7"=>1}
    },
 "fr"=>
    { "key1"=> 
        {"foo1"=>91, 
         "foo2"=>22, 
         "foo3"=>12}, 
      "key2"=>
        {"foo4"=>21,
         "foo5"=>31, 
         "foo6"=>27, 
         "foo7"=>11}
    }
}
require 'pp'
pp sort_deep(hash)
#=> {"en"=>
#=>   {"key1"=>{"foo2"=>2, "foo1"=>1, "foo3"=>1},
#=>    "key2"=>{"foo5"=>3, "foo6"=>2, "foo4"=>1, "foo7"=>1}},
#=>  "fr"=>
#=>   {"key1"=>{"foo1"=>91, "foo2"=>22, "foo3"=>12},
#=>    "key2"=>{"foo5"=>31, "foo6"=>27, "foo4"=>21, "foo7"=>11}}}
```